# MySQL/MariaDB GET_LOCK lifecyle with Events

Tags: mysql, events, locking, mariadb

I am attempting to use the `GET_LOCK()` functionality of MariaDB 10.0.19 to implement a system that limits events run by the event scheduler to only run one at a time.  Essentially each event tries to acquire a 'run_lock' and if successful it runs, otherwise it waits till the lock is available or times out.  The issue is, in testing, I can find many cases where my stored procedure does not release its lock even if it completes successfully.  Now I know when testing at the command line the lock is associated with my session - so if I exit the lock is released.  What I cannot seem to test/figure out is if an event terminates (normally or abnormally) will all of it's locks be released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I created two events as such

```
DELIMITER //

DROP EVENT IF EXISTS test_lock_1;

CREATE EVENT test_lock_1
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS NOW()
DO this_event:BEGIN

   SELECT GET_LOCK('test', 75);

   SELECT SLEEP(55);

END //

DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER //

DROP EVENT IF EXISTS test_lock_2;

CREATE EVENT test_lock_2
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 SECOND STARTS NOW()
DO this_event:BEGIN

   SELECT GET_LOCK('test', 25);

   SELECT SLEEP(45);

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Notice no releasing of the shared lock.  The lock did indeed get unlocked after the event exited, normally or abnormally.  So I surmise each event runs in it's own session and upon exit all locks are released.

Answer (score 0):

You should proceed only if the lock is obtained successfully

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE EVENT test_lock_1 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE DO 
BEGIN

  IF GET_LOCK('test', 30) IS TRUE THEN
    SELECT SLEEP(65);
  END IF;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```